# F1 Key go to MY support page?

Tags: php, javascript, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling key-press events (F1-F12) using JavaScript and jQuery, cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424407/handling-key-press-events-f1-f12-using-javascript-and-jquery-cross-browser)

how can i take my javascript code and make it go to my support document?

```
key['/'] = "support.php";   

function getKey(keyStroke) {
isNetscape=(document.layers);
eventChooser = (isNetscape) ? keyStroke.which : event.keyCode;
which = String.fromCharCode(eventChooser).toLowerCase();
for (var i in key) if (which == i) window.location = key[i];
}
document.onkeypress = getKey;
```

Comment: You should probably look at your window manager's system-wide shortcut keys to try to make `F1` do something different.

Answer (score 1):

As you'll see in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473496/overriding-the-f1-key-in-ff-chrome-ie-is-f1-on-ie8-chrome-on-keyup-and-in-ff), it's nearly impossible to achieve the behavior you desire cross-browser. You should use a different keyboard shortcut instead.